# why is dependency to javax.persistence-api removed in hibernate-core 6.0.2

Tags: java, hibernate

After updating hibernate-core from 5.6.9.Final to 6.0.2.Final my javax.persistence.Entity imports couldn't resolve. I discovered the dependency to javax.persistence-api is removed in hibernate-core 6.0.2.Final.

In 5.6.9.Final it's still here:
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.6.9.Final/jar

In 6.0.2.Final it's gone:
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/6.0.2.Final/pom

Can anyone please explain why it is removed?
Should I add it myself or is it missing (is it a bug) in 6.0.2.Final?

Comment: "Can anyone please explain why it is removed?" This is a question for manufactor.

Comment: HIbernate 6 is a JakartaEE implementation and not a JavaEE implementation. So no it isn't gone it uses a different API.

Comment: You should also switch your coordinates to [`org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core/6.0.2.Final/jar). Then you might have noticed that `javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api` had been **replaced** with `jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api` instead of simply removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hibernate 6 is an implementation of the Jakarta Persistence API **not** the Java Persistence API. See also the [initial release notes](https://in.relation.to/2022/03/31/orm-60-final/).

So no it is not a bug it is intended as there is no Java Persistence API after version 2.2, as the development/maintenance of the EE APIs has been moved from Oracle to a foundation. With the new releases the packages have also changed (due to legal implication) and those are now in `jakarta.persistence` instead of `javax.persistence`.

All this is also why there is en [extensive migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html) for moving to Hibernate 6.